# TimeDistributed-ing multiple layers at once

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have written the following script that reads a `yaml` specification of a CNN-RNN-FCN NN architecture and builds a corresponding Keras model:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Oct 27 10:22:03 2018

@author: jsevillamol
"""

import yaml, argparse
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input 
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import TimeDistributed, LSTM
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Dropout

def build_model(
        input_shape, 
        num_classes, 
        data_type,
        activation_function, 
        dropout_rate,
        use_batchnorm,
        cnn_layers,
        lstm_units,
        concat_lstm_output,
        fcn_layers):
    """
    Builds a CNN-RNN-FCN model according to some specs
    """

    # Build a model with the functional API
    inputs = Input(input_shape)
    x = inputs

    # CNN feature extractor    
    for i, cnn_layer in enumerate(cnn_layers):
        # Extract layer params
        filters = cnn_layer['filters']
        kernel_size = cnn_layer['kernel_size']
        use_maxpool = cnn_layer['use_maxpool']

        # build cnn_layer
        x = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(
                filters, 
                kernel_size, 
                strides=(1, 1), 
                padding='same', 
                data_format=None, 
                dilation_rate=(1, 1), 
                activation=activation_function, 
                use_bias=True, 
                kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', 
                bias_initializer='zeros', 
                kernel_regularizer=None, 
                bias_regularizer=None, 
                activity_regularizer=None, 
                kernel_constraint=None, 
                bias_constraint=None
            ), name=f'conv2D_{i}')(x)

        if use_batchnorm:
            x = TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization(
                    axis=-1, 
                    momentum=0.99, 
                    epsilon=0.001, 
                    center=True, 
                    scale=True, 
                    beta_initializer='zeros', 
                    gamma_initializer='ones', 
                    moving_mean_initializer='zeros', 
                    moving_variance_initializer='ones', 
                    beta_regularizer=None, 
                    gamma_regularizer=None, 
                    beta_constraint=None, 
                    gamma_constraint=None
                ), name=f'batchnorm_{i}')(x)


        # add maxpool if needed
        if use_maxpool:
            x = TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(
                    pool_size=(2, 2), 
                    strides=None, 
                    padding='valid', 
                    data_format=None
                ), name=f'maxpool_{i}')(x)

    x = TimeDistributed(Flatten(), name='flatten')(x)
    x = TimeDistributed(Dropout(dropout_rate), name='dropout')(x)

    # LSTM feature combinator
    x = LSTM(
            lstm_units, 
            activation='tanh', 
            recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid', 
            use_bias=True, 
            kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', 
            recurrent_initializer='orthogonal', 
            bias_initializer='zeros', 
            unit_forget_bias=True, 
            kernel_regularizer=None, 
            recurrent_regularizer=None, 
            bias_regularizer=None, 
            activity_regularizer=None, 
            kernel_constraint=None, 
            recurrent_constraint=None, 
            bias_constraint=None, 
            dropout=dropout_rate, 
            recurrent_dropout=0.0, 
            implementation=1, 
            return_sequences=concat_lstm_output, 
            return_state=False, 
            go_backwards=False, 
            stateful=False, 
            unroll=False
        )(x)

    if concat_lstm_output:
        x = Flatten()(x)

    # FCN classifier    
    for fcn_layer in fcn_layers:
        # extract layer params
        units = fcn_layer['units']

        # build layer
        x = Dense(
                units, 
                activation=activation_function, 
                use_bias=True, 
                kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', 
                bias_initializer='zeros', 
                kernel_regularizer=None, 
                bias_regularizer=None, 
                activity_regularizer=None, 
                kernel_constraint=None, 
                bias_constraint=None
            )(x)

        x = Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)


    prediction = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

    # Build model
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=prediction)

    return model

if __name__=="__main__":
    # parser options
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
            description=("Build a customized cnn-rnn keras model with ctalearn."))

    parser.add_argument(
            'config_file',
            help="path to YAML file containing a training configuration")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # load config file
    with open(args.config_file, 'r') as config_file:
        config = yaml.load(config_file)

    model = build_model(**config['model_config'])

    # Show model summary through console and then save it to file
    model.summary()

    with open('model_summary.txt', 'w') as f:
        with redirect_stdout(f):
            model.summary()

    # save model architecture to disk in .h5 format
    model.save('untrained_model.h5', include_optimizer=False)
```

I want to add a new feature to the program, that will allow to build models which accept as input examples with shape `(img_length, img_height, n_channels)`, i.e. a single image per example instead of a sequence as currently is.

For this it would be awesome to be able able to apply the `TimeDistributed` wrapper all at once after I build the CNN part of the model, so I do not have to add lots of conditionals everywhere.

How can I do that?

Comment: So currently the `input_shape` is `(n_frames, w, h, c)` and you want to accept the `input_shape` in the form of `(w, h, c)` with the minimal change to your code, right?

Comment: @today that is correct! To be 100% explicit, the code must preserve the ability to generate the models for the `(n_frames, w, h, c)` signature, and also be able to generate `(w, h, c)` models as indicated by a new parameter in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single image can be considered as a sequence of length one. Therefore, you can do this easily with a simple check and using `Reshape` layer:

```
inputs = Input(input_shape)
x = inputs

# if the input is a single image,
# reshape it to a sequence of length one
if len(input_shape) == 3:
    x = Reshape((1,) + input_shape)(x)

# the rest is the same
```